# Finding the value of this exponential limit

Tags: exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

The limit is given by
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty}\left(e^{\sqrt{x+1}}-e^{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}
$$

I don’t know where to start

Comment: Try to study the map $x\mapsto e^{\sqrt{x}}$ with the mean value theorem. The answer should be $e$.

Comment: @A.P., you are right, the limit is $e$.